# Kendo number formatting - without exponent

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a column in grid with type of float and I would like to have numbers displayed without 'e'. Is that possilbe?

e.g.

I don't want -1e-7, but -0.0000001.

What format should I use for that column?

Comment: if you post your code , would be easy to give a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. The problem is in Kendo DataSource, which automatically converts this kind of data. The solution is to have column template which would enforce formatting of value.

```
column.template = function(val) {
    return kendo.toString(parseFloat(val[column.name]), '#.#######');
}
```